# How do I calculate differences between sets of numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have statistics for various pro tennis players, and I'm trying to find a way to show the change in percentage for a given statistic across all players. I have data for a given player over two years, and each year has its own row in a python text file.
For instance, if I want to search for % of service games won (I've displayed those percentages in decimal form), I want an outfile to show up with different rows, each with the following information: Player name, and +/- in that statistic between those two years. Here is the data I'm working on currently, and the first lines of code just setting it up:

Murray, 2015, 2, .75, .47, .52, .64, .84, .55, .45, .31

Murray, 2016, 1, .76, .46, .54, .66, .85, .56, .45, .37

---

```
infile = open("/Users/student/PycharmProjects/untitled6/final project data", 'r')
outfile = open("/Users/student/PycharmProjects/untitled6/.idea/final project outfile", 'w')
playerinfo = []
header = infile.readline()
tennisdata = []

for aline in infile:
    info = aline.split(',')
    playerinfo.append(info)
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing that can be achieved in a matter of 2 lines with numpy or pandas. Or are you looking for a vanilla python solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in python (very new to using python here)

Comment: The first value after the year... 2/1... those aren't %, so what are they?

Comment: I forgot about those, those are the year-end rankings for the player